# defining setf-expanders in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, setf

Here's the thing: I don't "get" setf-expanders and would like to learn how they work.

I need to learn how they work because I've got a problem which seems like a typical example for why you should learn setf-expanders, the problem is as follows:

```
(defparameter some-array (make-array 10))

(defun arr-index (index-string)
  (aref some-array (parse-integer index-string))

(setf (arr-index "2") 7) ;; Error: undefined function (setf arr-index)
```

How do I write a proper setf-expander for ARR-INDEX?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
(defun (setf arr-index) (new-value index-string)
  (setf (aref some-array (parse-integer index-string))
        new-value))
```

In Common Lisp a [function name](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_name) can not only be a symbol, but also a list of two symbols with `SETF` as the first symbol. See above. `DEFUN` thus can define `SETF` functions. The name of the function is `(setf arr-index)`.

A *setf function* can be used in a *place* form: [CLHS: Other compound forms as places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abi.htm).

The new value is the first argument then.

```
CL-USER 15 > some-array
#(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)

CL-USER 16 > (setf (arr-index "2") 7)
7

CL-USER 17 > some-array
#(NIL NIL 7 NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

Comment: I couldn't find this in the CLHS, where is it?

Comment: @Nowhereman: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_name

Comment: I had seen it in the glossary, but where is it explained how to define a setf function with (defun (setf foo)...)?

Comment: @Nowhereman: there is no direct explanation. But it's defined that a setf function can be used in a place form and that `defun` can define functions with a setf name.

Comment: `#'(setf arr-index)` is now a function that you can call. It's what the setf macro expands to, that is `(funcall #'(setf arr-index) new-value index-string)`.

Comment: In addition to the glossary definition cited above, this is discussed in CLHS 5.1.2.9: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abi.htm

Answer (score 6):

Rainer's answer is spot on. Before ANSI Common Lisp, it was necessary to use `defsetf` to define an expander for simple places that could be set with a simple function call. `setf` functions like `(setf arr-index)` came into the language with CLOS and simplify a lot of things. In particular, `setf` functions can be generic.