# what is to append as push is to cons, in Lisp?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

```
(push x list)
```

expands to

```
(setq list (cons x list))
```

What expands to the following:

```
(setq list (append list2 list))
```

? Is there a standard macro for this?

Comment: I believe there is no such macro, but you may write it yourself :)

Comment: You may have a look at *nconc*, which is not exactly what you ask for, but a bit similar.

Comment: @arbautjc Isn't nconc also supposed to be used with setq? Either (setq list (nconc list-to-prepend list))   or (setq list (nconc list list-to-append-at-end)). In both cases, setq is necessary.

Comment: No, *nconc* modifies all but its last argument (see [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nconc.htm)). You can try this: (defparameter a '(1 2 3))
(defparameter b '(4 5 6))
(nconc a b), then
a => (1 2 3 4 5 6)
b => (4 5 6), without using *setq*.

Comment: @arbautjc `nconc` should still be used with `setq` though, because the first argument could be `nil`.  E.g., `(let ((x '())
               (y '(1 2 3)))
           (nconc x y)
           x)` evaluates to `()`.  To cover this case, it's safer to do `(setq x (nconc x y))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [defining setf-expanders in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457071/defining-setf-expanders-in-common-lisp)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As other answers and comments have pointed out, there's not a standard macro for this, and you can write your own.  In my opinion, this is a good case for [`define-modify-macro`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_defi_2.htm#define-modify-macro), and I'll describe that first.  You can also write such a macro manually, using [`get-setf-expansion`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get_se.htm), and I'll show an example of that, too.

### Using `define-modify-macro`

One of the examples on the HyperSpec page for `define-modify-macro` is `appendf`:

> #### Description:
>
> define-modify-macro defines a macro named name to read and write a place.
>
> The arguments to the new macro are a place, followed by the arguments that are supplied in lambda-list. Macros defined with define-modify-macro correctly pass the environment parameter to get-setf-expansion.
>
> When the macro is invoked, function is applied to the old contents of the place and the lambda-list arguments to obtain the new value, and the place is updated to contain the result.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> (define-modify-macro appendf (&rest args) 
>    append "Append onto list") =>  APPENDF
> (setq x '(a b c) y x) =>  (A B C)
> (appendf x '(d e f) '(1 2 3)) =>  (A B C D E F 1 2 3)
> x =>  (A B C D E F 1 2 3)
> y =>  (A B C)
> ```

The `appendf` in the example is reversed from what you're looking for, since the extra arguments are appended as the tail of the `place` argument.  However, we can write the functional version of the desired behavior (it's just `append` with argument order swapped), and then use `define-modify-macro`:

```
(defun swapped-append (tail head)
  (append head tail))

(define-modify-macro swapped-appendf (&rest args)
  swapped-append)

(let ((x '(1 2 3))
      (y '(4 5 6)))
  (swapped-appendf x y)
  x)
; => (4 5 6 1 2 3)
```

If you don't want to define `swapped-append` as a function, you can give a `lambda`-expression to `define-modify-macro`:

```
(define-modify-macro swapped-appendf (&rest args)
  (lambda (tail head) 
    (append head tail)))

(let ((x '(1 2 3))
      (y '(4 5 6)))
  (swapped-appendf x y)
  x)
; => (4 5 6 1 2 3)
```

So, the answer is that, conceptually, `(swapped-appendf list list2)` expands to `(setq list (append list2 list))`.  It's still the case that the arguments to `swapped-appendf` may seem to be in the wrong order.  After all, if we defined `push` using `define-modify-macro` and `cons`, the arguments would be in a different order from the standard `push`:

```
(define-modify-macro new-push (&rest args)
  (lambda (list item)
    (cons item list)))

(let ((x '(1 2 3)))
  (new-push x 4)
  x)
; => (4 1 2 3)
```

`define-modify-macro` is a handy tool to know about, and I've found it useful when functional (i.e., non-side-effecting) versions of functions are easy to write and a modifying version is also desired for an API.

### Using `get-setf-expansion`

`new-push`'s arguments are `list` and `item`, whereas `push`'s arguments are `item` and `list`. I don't think the argument order in `swapped-appendf` is quite as important, since it's not a standard idiom.  However, it is possible to achieve the other order by writing a `prependf` macro whose implementation uses [`get-setf-expansion`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_se.htm) to safely get the [Setf Expansion](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_aab.htm) for the place, and to avoid multiple evaluation.

```
(defmacro prependf (list place &environment environment)
  "Store the value of (append list place) into place."
  (let ((list-var (gensym (string '#:list-))))
    (multiple-value-bind (vars vals store-vars writer-form reader-form)
        (get-setf-expansion place environment)
      ;; prependf works only on a single place, so there
      ;; should be a single store-var.  This means we don't
      ;; handle, e.g., (prependf '(1 2 3) (values list1 list2))
      (destructuring-bind (store-var) store-vars
        ;; Evaluate the list form (since its the first argument) and
        ;; then bind all the temporary variables to the corresponding
        ;; value forms, and get the initial value of the place.
        `(let* ((,list-var ,list)
                ,@(mapcar #'list vars vals)
                (,store-var ,reader-form))
           (prog1 (setq ,store-var (append ,list-var ,store-var))
             ,writer-form))))))

(let ((x '(1 2 3))
      (y '(4 5 6)))
  (prependf y x)
  x)
; => (4 5 6 1 2 3)
```

The use of `get-setf-expansion` means that this macro works on more complicated places, too:

```
(let ((x (list 1 2 3))
      (y (list 4 5 6)))
  (prependf y (cddr x))
  x)
; => (1 2 4 5 6 3)
```

For educational purposes, it's interesting to see the relevant macroexpansions, and how they avoid multiple evaluations of the forms, and what the `writer-form`s are that are used to actually set the value.  There's a lot of functionality bundled into `get-setf-expansion`, and some of it is implementation specific:

```
;; lexical variables just use SETQ
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(prependf y x)))
(LET* ((#:LIST-885 Y)
       (#:NEW886 X))
  (PROG1 (SETQ #:NEW886 (APPEND #:LIST-885 #:NEW886))
    (SETQ X #:NEW886)))

;; (CDDR X) gets an SBCL internal RPLACD
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(prependf y (cddr x))))
(LET* ((#:LIST-882 Y)
       (#:G883 X)
       (#:G884 (CDDR #:G883)))
  (PROG1 (SETQ #:G884 (APPEND #:LIST-882 #:G884))
    (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACD (CDR #:G883) #:G884)))

;; Setting in an array gets another SBCL internal ASET function
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(prependf y (aref some-array i j))))
(LET* ((#:LIST-887 Y)
       (#:TMP891 SOME-ARRAY)
       (#:TMP890 I)
       (#:TMP889 J)
       (#:NEW888 (AREF #:TMP891 #:TMP890 #:TMP889)))
  (PROG1 (SETQ #:NEW888 (APPEND #:LIST-887 #:NEW888))
    (SB-KERNEL:%ASET #:TMP891 #:TMP890 #:TMP889 #:NEW888)))
```

Comment: Nice solution. Maybe we could rename this macro *prependf* ? :-)

Comment: the argument order in the *call* `(.... tail head)`  feels unnatural IMHO. You do this just to be able to use the `define-modify-macro`, because it treats the first arg as the place to set, but here it is natural to treat the 2nd arg that way.

Comment: @WillNess It doesn't feel as unnatural to me since it's sort of an unusual operator, but I've updated the answer with a `get-setf-expansion` based macro that gets the arguments in the other order.

Comment: yep, you most certainly did. :) :) a real tour de force!

Answer (score 3):

To clarify things a bit, about Vatine's answer:

With the initial question, we have

```
(defparameter list '(1 2 3))
(defparameter list2 '(4 5 6))
(setq list (append list2 list))

list
(4 5 6 1 2 3)

list2
(4 5 6)
```

That is, list2 is prepended to list, but list2 is not itself modified. The reason is simply that *append* does not change directly its arguments.

Now, with

```
(defmacro tail-push (place val)
  (let ((tmp (gensym "TAIL")))
    `(let ((,tmp ,place))
        (setf (cdr (last ,tmp)) ,val)
        ,tmp)))
```

First try

```
(defparameter list '(1 2 3))
(defparameter list2 '(4 5 6))
(tail-push list2 list)

list
(1 2 3)

list2
(4 5 6 1 2 3)
```

Second try, switching the arguments

```
(defparameter list '(1 2 3))
(defparameter list2 '(4 5 6))
(tail-push list list2)

list
(1 2 3 4 5 6)

list2
(4 5 6)
```

Either way, one of the list is appended to the other, simply because *nconc*, or (rplacd (last ...) ...) or here, directly (setf (cdr (last ...)) ...), **can only append, not prepend**. And we can't just claim that the first try gives the right answer '(4 5 6 1 2 3), because *list* was not modified, whereas *list2* was, which is absolutely not what was required.

However, with Joshua's solution,

```
(defun swapped-append (tail head)
  (append head tail))

(define-modify-macro swapped-appendf (&rest args)
  swapped-append)

(defparameter list '(1 2 3))
(defparameter list2 '(4 5 6))
(swapped-appendf list list2)

list
(4 5 6 1 2 3)

list2
(4 5 6)
```

And it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Joshua Taylor mentioned how to do it in Common Lisp. I will answer how in Emacs Lisp:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(defmacro appendf (place &rest lists)
  `(cl-callf append ,place ,@lists))
(defmacro prependf (list place)
  `(cl-callf2 append ,list ,place))
```

And some test:

```
(let ((to-prepend '(the good))
      (acc '(the bad))
      (to-append-1 '(the weird))
      (to-append-2 '(pew pew)))
  (prependf to-prepend acc)
  (appendf acc to-append-1 to-append-2)
  (list :acc acc
        :to-prepend to-prepend
        :to-append-1 to-append-1
        :to-append-2 to-append-2))
; ⇒ (:acc (the good the bad the weird pew pew) :to-prepend (the good) :to-append-1 (the weird) :to-append-2 (pew pew))
```

Macro expansion test:

```
(let ((print-gensym t))
  (print
   (macroexpand '(prependf y (cddr x)))))
; prints (let* ((#:a1 y) (#:v x)) (setcdr (cdr #:v) (append #:a1 (cddr #:v))))
```

For macroexpand-1 and pretty printing, use the macrostep package.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there's nothing ready-made, but it should be relatively easy to make one.

```
(defmacro tail-push (place val)
  (let ((tmp (gensym "TAIL")))
    `(let ((,tmp ,place))
        (setf (cdr (last ,tmp)) ,val)
        ,tmp)))
```

Comment: @arbautjc Er, that's rather the *point* of this macro. `(push a b)` puts a at the head of b, `(tail-push a b)` puts b at the tail of a. Nicely symmetric. Changed the name to `place` to be even more descriptive.

Comment: Certainly symmetric, but not what was asked by the OP, that is, not the equivalent of (setq list (append list2 list)). You see, it's the *tail* (list, not list2) that should be changed. What your macro does is exactly (nconc place val).

Comment: The point that @arbautjc still stands though;  you can do `(let ((x '())) (push 'a x))`, and afterward `x` is `(a)`.  However, `(let ((x '())) (tail-push x '(a)))` signals an error (because of `(last nil)`).  This means that `tail-push` fails in some of the cases that `(nconc place val)` would have worked, and that a `nconcf` defined by `define-modify-macro` would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

if `(push x lst)` expands as `(setf lst (cons x lst))` then just make a macro `prepend` such that the call `(prepend xs lst)` would expand as `(setf lst (append xs lst))`:

```
(defmacro prepend (a b) 
  `(setf ,b (append ,a ,b)))
```

the 2nd argument must denote a *place*, but so it must be for `push` as well.

You will have to be careful to not have lengthy heavy calculations inside the *place* argument there, or else:

```
[14]> (setq x (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
((1 2) (3 4))
[15]> (prepend '(a b c) (nth (print (- 1 1)) x))

0             ;; calculated and
0             ;;   printed twice!
(A B C 1 2)
[16]> x
((A B C 1 2) (3 4))
```